# Bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

Will anybody help develop a bar plot using `ggplot2` for this data:

[image]

I am unable to develop a barplot for this data.

Answer (score 1):

In ggplot you should make your data in a longer format. For this you could use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`. With that you could create a stacked barplot like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Valley = c("Hushey", "Kanday", "Thallay"),
                 Female = c(144, 43, 45),
                 Young = c(160, 43, 22),
                 Yearling = c(162, 20, 25))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Valley) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Valley, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Or make a facet plot using `facet_wrap` like this:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Valley) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Valley)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>